# What is the best way to save small setting for an android app, inside a text file or using SQL?

Tags: android, sqlite

If I have an Android app and there are some settings for the app, what is the best way to save them, inside a text file or using SQL?

Comment: Shared preferences.

Comment: Either of those can be appropriate, depending on how much and the types of data being stored.  So can a JSON file, xml, or shared preferences (which is a xml file managed by the OS with a build in API in Android).  Really any of them is fine, it's what's most convenient for you.  Generally for small unstructured or changing structured data, that's shared preferences, text, or JSON.  SQL can be a bit of a pain with migrations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best way use sql lite and save the data inside the database, because
more secure , performance and data recovery

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).